# GitBash: How can I pass an argument that starts with a slash / without it seen as a directory?

Tags: bash, aws-cli, git-bash, msys

On Windows10 using Git Bash...

I'm using aws cli to get a parameter from ssm. The names argument begins with "/". This is processed by bash as a directory name and results in an error. (Command works in CentOS. It works in PowerShell. I'd like to stay inside Git Bash.)

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2
```

Response:

```
{
    "Parameters": [],
    "InvalidParameters": [
        "C:/Program Files/Git/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2"
    ]
}
```

I've tried quoting and escaping...

```
... "/aws/..."
... '/aws/...'
... \/aws/...
... \/aws\/...
... \\/aws/...
... \\/aws\\...
```

I've tried putting into a variable, but the result is the same.

I tried turning off globbing. (I verified "*" is no longer expanded, but I still have the same problem.)

```
set -f
```

I can't find a way to make the command work in GitBash.

Do you happen to know a solution?

Comment: git-bash really has more to do with msys (the translation layer to make it compile on Windows) than with git (which it happens to be distributed with, but has no other relationship to). It's msys doing this unwanted work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this :

```
MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 aws ssm ...
```

If this does not work, or causes other problems, try

```
aws ssm ... //aws\\service...
```

which is replacing the first forward slash by doubling it and replacing all the remaining forward slashes by two backslashes.

Comment: Thanks @Philippe. Neither of those worked for me, but got me in the right direction. Could you edit your answer to include this solution? This worked for me. 

Double-slash the front, replace other slashes with double-backslash:

aws ssm ... //aws\\service\\ami-ama...

Answer (score 2):

What helped me was when I added whitespace before the slash.

```
aws ssm put-parameter --name ' /bla/bla/bla' --type String --overwrite --value 1
```